# Can I play a save from the non-GOTY edition of Red Dead Redemption in the GOTY edition?

Tags: ps3, red-dead-redemption

My friend is able to lend me *Red Dead Redemption*. However it's the vanilla edition, so I'm going to end up buying the GOTY edition anyway. Here is a question now: If I were to play *Red Dead Redemption*, non-GOTY edition, have a save from it, and then buy the GOTY edition, will I be able to play on the save I made while playing the non-GOTY edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have contacted Rockstar support and they have confirmed that save files are interchangeable between the standard edition and the Game of the year edition.

This means that any save created with the vanilla edition will load up no problem when you get the GOTY edition.

Answer (score 1):

The DLC in the GOTY edition does not affect the main story mode as the DLC is all multiplayer based except for Undead Nightmare, which is stand-alone.  You can purchase the GOTY edition after playing the vanilla version and you save will be okay.

Comment: Do you know this for sure? I had a similar problem with another rockstar game, LA Noire, where my vanilla save would not load on the GOTY edition. While this may not effect DLC it would be an issue if the OP wants to switch editions before he finishes the massive single player mode. I have down voted until the information you have provide can be verified as I think there is a high chance it is incorrect.

Comment: Since LA Noire is singleplayer only, the DLC would affect the save.  All the DLC included in the Red Dead GOTY edition is multiplayer **only**.  In fact, the GOTY edition comes with the singleplayer on one disc, and the multiplayer with its DLC on another.  If OP was really paranoid, they could not insert the second disc until they were done with the singleplayer.

Comment: I think the OP wants to switch editions on the middle of the single player game and wants to know if he can load a save from the vanilla to GOTY edition. I know for a fact you cannot do this in LA noire. Your answer and comment are purely related to DLC and do not address that fundamental part of the question.

Comment: I answered his question in my answering saying `You can purchase the GOTY edition after playing the vanilla version and you save will be okay.`  The rest of my answer was providing evidence for my answer.

Comment: That statement itself is ambiguous. What does "your save will be okay." actually mean? It does not answer the question of whether he could switch editions mid way through the single player and continue with the same save file which is really what the OP is asking. Also you have provided no source for you assurance that it will be 'okay,' how do you know this?

Comment: You're being difficult now.  You're trying to shoot down my answer without contributing anything useful.  "Your save will be okay" means exactly that.  They can switch games and be fine.  Unless OP is incredibly dense, they should know what I mean.  I have no source, only the logic I presented in my answer.  This is a hard question to answer with a source as a case of going from standard to GOTY with this game is rare.  However, I am confident in this answer as I own the GOTY edition myself and know that the singleplayer is contained on one disk and DLC on another.

Comment: So you have just admitted that your answer is a guess. My guess is that it would probably not work based on my experience with other Rockstar games (see above) however I would not post that as an answer because it is just a guess. I am investigating this to try and find a definitive answer and will post my own answer if I can find out for certain. I think your original answer was not clear or helpful, I am not trying to be difficult just raise the quality of information provided.